# Vue & Jest - How to test a method with parameters? With vue/test-utils NOT jest-dom

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

After a lot of research I was finally able to test an method with the follow code

```js
  it('should call myFunction - on Desktop', async () => {
    const mockMethod = jest.spyOn(myComponent.methods, 'myFunction')
    const wrapper = shallowMount(
      myComponent,
      {
        store,
        localVue,
        propsData,
        stubs,
      },
    )
    await wrapper.findAll('.container button-stub').at(0).trigger('click')
    expect(mockMethod).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
```

And it worked :pray-pep:
But know I need to test an method passing an parameter and comparing the result.
This method changes my data, my data is like follows

```js
  data () {
    return {
      myOptions: [],
    }
  },
```

This method adds the argument, that is an number, in myOptions. That is what an want to test, call the function and compare if the parameter passed was added to myOptions

Sorry for my english and talks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myFunction` is the method you speak of, and it's called like this:

```js
this.myFunction(123)
```

You could use Jest's [`toHaveBeenCalledWith()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-) assertion to verify it was called with specific arguments, and then check the value of `myOptions`:

```js
expect(mockMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123)
expect(wrapper.vm.myOptions).toInclude(123)
```